# Using decltype to declare the entire function type itself (not pointer!)

Tags: c++, c++17, decltype

So I have a function with a specific signature in a header file, and I want to declare another function with the exact same signature inside a class **without** typing the parameters again, and of course, hopefully without a macro... The member function should also have an extra hidden parameter obviously, the `this` pointer (since it's not a static member function).

Now, I'm actually surprised that the following hack/trick *works* in both GCC and ICC, but I'm not sure if it's "legal" C++. I'm not particularly concerned with legality *if it's a supported extension*, but unfortunately I do not want it to break on a compiler version update because some people decided to *arbitrarily block* this useful feature since the standard says "no" (that kind of stuff really annoys me to be honest).

Here's what I mean:

```
// test.hpp
int func(int x) { return x; }

struct foo
{
  decltype(func) fn;  // <-- legal?
};

int test()
{
  return foo().fn(6);
}


// then in test.cpp
int foo::fn(int x) { return x + 42; }
```

This *works* (with GCC and ICC), but I don't know if it's "legal" in the standard. I'm asking just to be assured that it is legal and it won't suddenly stop working in the future.

(if it's not legal and you want to report it as a bug, please mark it as a suggestion to make it a legal compiler extension instead of killing it...)

Basically, it's the same as declaring `int fn(int x);` in the struct, and that's how it works currently.

If you ask me for a use case: it's to declare a wrapper member function for the other free function which does something with the `this` pointer before passing it to the free function. Its parameters must match exactly, obviously. Again, I don't want to type the parameters again.

Comment: It's legal as long as it's not a dependent type in a class template.

Comment: For extra abuse you can "initialize" it with "= 0;" and make it virtual

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Interesting, and off topic, but curious: what does initializing it with 0 do? I only know you can "initialize" it with = delete.

Comment: @kktsuri I'm assuming he's talking about making a pure virtual function

Comment: @Justin Ah yes I see thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks legal; but at definition you have to retype.  Consider using perfect forwarding instead.

Comment: You're right but, how can I use perfect forwarding when it's defined in another translation unit (cpp file)? I mean I can make it "extern template" (or just leave it undefined) in the header file (declaration), but won't instantiating be an issue? Can you provide an example without requiring to type it (well, re-typing the free function `func` is fine, obviously). Maybe I'm just overlooking something simple.

Comment: Anyway, I will accept your answer since it answers the question, but it would be nice to know about perfect forwarding with a different translation unit (the actual functions have more complicated operations and I want to keep them in one place, as I compile with LTO they will be inlined anyway even across translation units). Thanks

Comment: What strikes me as odd is that the type of `fn` and `func` are not the same `static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(&foo::fn), decltype(&func)>{}, "");` I see how it would work legally as OP has it, but could also imagine the `decltype` not being allowed here since `fn` isn't of type `int(int)`

Comment: @RyanHaining `using sig=int(int); struct foo{ sig f; };` makes `foo:f` have signature `int(int)`.  It isn't a type, but rather a signature, you are applying here.